# Portable Electron App

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

I have an application which based on git electron. (For windows)

I need this app to be portable on USB disk and also I want this app to have auto-update feature.

Grunt-electron-installer uses [squirrel.windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) for update mechanism. Squirrel uses SHGetFolderPath function with CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA to decide installation path which is normally *C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\$pkgName*.

My question is;

- Is there a better way to use as auto-update feature for portable electron apps?
- I could use [Enigma virtual box](http://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html) as a virtual system to overcome squirrel.windows path problem. In this option I need a way to change CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA variable in virtual system. Any idea?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you